# Cropping with Jcrop and PHP GD creates black JPEG

Tags: javascript, php, image

I'm working on an image Upload/Crop feature, utilising [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html). The first part works fine, but implementing the Crop is causing headaches. I've looked at [the](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551747/why-does-this-basic-imagejpeg-resizer-returns-a-black-image&ei=EdGiU-2GF_DG7Ab0wIHQBA&usg=AFQjCNHDhACeqP-N1hqj7gu_nt_gMdyt-g) [following](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382189/imagecreatefromjpeg-returns-a-black-image-after-resize&ei=EdGiU-2GF_DG7Ab0wIHQBA&usg=AFQjCNHhwr7oHUtauOzvyEuwdgR-LKwz3w) [questions](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267712/php-image-upload-resize-creates-black-image&ei=EdGiU-2GF_DG7Ab0wIHQBA&usg=AFQjCNEmOWpN-LLkFeqobZIxssOXX93J8A), and none seem completely relevant to my problem.

My form that creates the upload:

```
<img src="uploads/<?=$image_name?>" id="crop-me">
<form action="complete.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="<?=$image_name?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="x" id="x">
    <input type="hidden" name="y" id="y">
    <input type="hidden" name="x2" id="x2">
    <input type="hidden" name="y2" id="y2">
    <input type="hidden" name="w" id="w">
    <input type="hidden" name="h" id="h">
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crop</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#crop-me').Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 130 / 170, // 0.7647
        minSize: [130, 170],
        setSelect: [260, 340, 0, 0],
        onChange: showCoords,
        onSelect: showCoords
    });
    function showCoords(c) {
        $("#x").val(c.x);
        $("#y").val(c.y);
        $("#x2").val(c.x2);
        $("#y2").val(c.y2);
        $("#w").val(c.w);
        $("#h").val(c.h);
    }
});
```

And finally, `complete.php` which does the image generation:

```
<?php

$targ_w = 130;
$targ_h = 170;
$jpeg_quality = 100;

$src = 'uploads' . $_POST['image_name'];
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);

imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $targ_w, $targ_h, $_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r, null, $jpeg_quality);

?>
```

I do get an image on `complete.php`, at 130x170 dimensions, but it's completely black. I *think* it might be something to do with an aspect ratio calculation/misalignment (the code I am using is a direct rip from Jcrop's [tutorial/manual](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html), but with different widths and heights), but I'm really not sure.

Can someone see where I'm going wrong?

*Note: I've checked, and the server is definitely running the GD extension, v2.x*

Comment: Do you need a slash after "uploads"? `$src = 'uploads/' ...`

Comment: Why yes, yes I do. Thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by `@BloodyKnuckles`, there was a typo in this line:

`$src = 'uploads' . $_POST['image_name'];`

A `/` was missing at the end of the `uploads` folder name, and should have read:

`$src = 'uploads/' . $_POST['image_name'];`